# glib regex can't work in c

Tags: c

why \w pattern can't match?and many pattern can't work,eg:\s

my os is Mac

I think maybe missing something;

that code only match char 'w',don't sam.

thank your help

```
//
//  main.c
//  test
//
//  Created by SamPeng on 12-9-22.
//  Copyright (c) 2012年 SamPeng. All rights reserved.
//

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int status,i;
    int cflags = REG_EXTENDED;
    regmatch_t pmatch[1];
    const size_t nmatch=1;
    regex_t reg;
    const char *pattern="\\w";
    char *buf = "sam@sampengw.org";

    regcomp(&reg, pattern, cflags);
    status = regexec(&reg, buf, nmatch, pmatch, 0);

    if(status == REG_NOMATCH)
        printf("No Match \n");
    else if(status == 0){
        printf("Match:\n");
        for (i=pmatch[0].rm_so; i<pmatch[0].rm_eo; ++i) {
            putchar(buf[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    regfree(&reg);
    return 0;
}
```

complement:
yes,I know this work is POSIX Base reg,how change this? I wan't use powerful regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glib regex module supports [POSIX extended regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html#ere), which allow only a small subset of modern regular expression syntax, due to having been standardized in 1986.  For shorthand classes like `\w` and `\s`, you want either the [GNU extensions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#ere) (available in [Gnulib](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/)) or the [PCRE library](http://www.pcre.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Glib regex does not support the common `\` shorthand for common character classes. It does support POSIX character classes (eg `[[:space:]]`) so you can use that if you would like. Otherwise you can explicitly use the character set with no shorthand (eg `[ \t\n]`).

There is very good documentation in the regex man page about this.

Comment: thank you,if I wan't use support common regex,have some suggest?

Comment: Both answers are confusing glibc's regex with glib regex. These are different libraries. The former is "standard" regexp and therefore doesn't support Perl's \w, \s etc. The regex in glib does support Perl syntax.